How can we write to ledger space?
According to this question there is two ways to write data to ledger space:

Call data (and accounts) in transactions
Logging inside programs

Is there any other ways?

You've got it all correct -- the ledger is just transaction data, so those are your two ways of writing to the ledger. You might also want to know that additional data like logging, CPI info, and return data are not stored by default in the ledger, and validators / RPC nodes need to opt into it.
